# connectivity of virtuoso with asp.net visual studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, virtuoso

i want to connect virtuoso with visual studio 2015 but the option SQL AdapterData is missing . how can make connections between these two.

Comment: Did you install VS2015 before Virtuoso?

Comment: The Virtuoso DataAdapter does not currently auto-register with VS2015. You can manually adjust the Registry, as [described in this article](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksEnableAdoNetProviderInVS2010).